# Update Apollo store after filtered query

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a list of items which can be filtered out using certain criteria. Whenever i perform a search, i want to grab a filtered item and update its content which seems to update the apollo store correctly, but for some reason changes are not being shown. Perhaps the componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method is not being fired and i need to implement it by myself?
I tried updating the store manually using "update" after the mutation but it wont work also.

This is my code so far:

#### ClientList.js

```
class ClientList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      hasMoreItems: true,
      loading: false,
      clients: [],
      searchText: ''
    }
  }

  _executeSearch = async () => {
    const { searchText } = this.state;

    this.setState({ loading: true });

    const result = await this.props.client.query({
      query: ALL_CLIENTS_QUERY,
      variables: { searchText },
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
    })

    this.setState({
      clients: result.data.allClients,
      loading: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    let { allClients, loading, fetchMore } = this.props.data;
    const { hasMoreItems, clients, searchText } = this.state;

    if (clients.length > 0) {
      allClients = clients;
      loading = this.state.loading;
    }

    return (
      <section>
        <h1 className="text-center">Clients</h1>
        <InputGroup>
          <InputGroupButton>
            <Button onClick={() => this._executeSearch()}>I'm a button</Button>
          </InputGroupButton>
          <Input
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ searchText: e.target.value })}
            placeholder="Search by social or comercial name"
          />
        </InputGroup>
        {loading ?
          <div className="text-center mt-4">
            <i className="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
          </div>
        : <div className="mt-3">
            {allClients.map(client =>
              <div key={`client-${client.id}`} className="client-content">
                <Link to={`/clients/${client.id}`}>
                  <h1 className="mb-1">
                    {client.socialName}
                    <small className="text-muted ml-3">{client.comercialName}</small>
                  </h1>
                </Link>
              </div>
            })
          </div>
      </section>
    );
  };
}

export default withApollo(graphql(ALL_CLIENTS_QUERY)(ClientList));
```

#### ClientEdit.js

```
class ClientEdit extends Component {
  onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ loading: true });

    const payload = {
      id: this.props.match.params.id,
      rfc: this.state.rfc,
      socialName: this.state.socialName,
      legalRepresentative: this.state.legalRepresentative,
      comercialName: this.state.comercialName
    }
     // Mutation updates the store but doesnt show results
    const resp = await this.props.mutate({
      variables: payload,
      update: (store, { data: { updateClient } }) => {
        // Tried updating but it doesnt show changes also;
      }
    });
  }
}

export default compose(
  graphql(GET_CLIENT_QUERY, {
    options: props => ({
      variables: {
        id: props.match.params.id
      }
    })
  }),
  graphql(UPDATE_CLIENT_MUTATION)
)(ClientEdit);
```

Answer (score 0):

better if we check that the data is ready and we can render it out , and when data still fetching so no render associated with that apollo data object should be done:

```
render(){
    const {loading} = this.props.data;
    if(loading) {return <div>Loading...</div>}
    return (
           ...
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix this using the componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method. I dont know if this is a bug or maybe there is another solution;

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    const { allClients, loading } = newProps.data;

    if (!loading) {
      const clients = _.intersectionBy(allClients, this.state.clients, 'id');
      this.setState({ clients });
    }
  }
```